# Yet another login loop problem with Nvidia Graphics Driver install

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, login, 16.04

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I followed close instruction on how to install the nvidia drivers. I did `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*` then I did

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

Then I did `sudo apt-get update.` and then `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`

I rebooted and everything worked. I should also mention that my grub file has "nomodeset quiet splash' written in it. I started up Nvidia server and made sure Nvidia Graphics was selected. It was also selected in settings/updates and software/additional drivers (364).

Now when I restart, I got the black screen. I then took out nomodeset to see if that would help. I get to the login screen but of course, it keeps coming back to that over and over. Could someone please tell what the working solution for this is? I've gone through 3 installs of Ubuntu: 14.04,15.10 and now 16.04 to see if it would work and for each I get the same problem.

I'm using a Dell i7559 laptop with GTX960M graphics card.

Comment: You should have started with sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  (No hyphen)

Comment: Do the default graphics drivers not work? the Ubuntu graphics PPA could possibly break your system and you are allowed to keep both halves.

Comment: So I should just click on what's there already? No installing PPA or any of that? I'll try that. I swear that I tried this already on an older install and ran into the loop login problem.

Comment: Many skylake cpu's with nvidia mobile gpu's can't not boot up/log in while on the nvidia drivers. Couple of reports based on my hardware - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1565516 & https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1583148 If affected then currently no workaround, use the intel iGPU or windows 10

Comment: `nvidia-current` is a wrong driver for this adapter.